All possible Hebrew and Yiddish characters (including niqqud)
I am trying to bruteforce a solution to a puzzle which I suspect to be a word written using the Hebrew alphabet. It might be written using niqqud and it might not.
In order to understand how long my solution will take, I would like to know how many possible Hebrew or Yiddish characters there are, including niqqud. So for example:
פ
פִ
פֿ
are all different characters and I care about each of them.
Please, could you either provide a list of all characters or a way for me to generate one? I don't speak Hebrew and I don't know how the niqqud works precisely.

The following is a comprehensive list of letter+nikkud combinations appearing in the Tanakh (texts taken from https://www.tanach.us/) filtering out extremely rare variants (<10 appearances) and their frequencies:
  27487 א
     50 אְ
   3668 אֱ
  12000 אֲ
     52 אֳ
   5347 אִ
   9696 אֵ
  17228 אֶ
   8197 אַ
   8899 אָ
   2860 אֹ
    548 אֻ
  10458 ב
   7412 בְ
  10598 בְּ
     18 בֳּ
   4076 בִ
   2476 בִּ
   2254 בֵ
   2839 בֵּ
   2062 בֶ
   1970 בֶּ
   2914 בַ
   4707 בַּ
   5329 בָ
   4660 בָּ
   1852 בֹ
    628 בֹּ
    204 בֻ
     31 בֻּ
   1027 בּ
    901 ג
   1518 גְ
    895 גְּ
    421 גִ
    965 גִּ
    267 גֵ
    328 גֵּ
    412 גֶ
    194 גֶּ
    774 גַ
    911 גַּ
    655 גָ
    842 גָּ
    108 גֹ
    184 גֹּ
     50 גֻ
     53 גֻּ
    653 גּ
  10906 ד
   2793 דְ
   1120 דְּ
     64 דֳּ
   1448 דִ
   1672 דִּ
    940 דֵ
    341 דֵּ
   1586 דֶ
    510 דֶּ
   1818 דַ
    760 דַּ
   4252 דָ
   2218 דָּ
   1317 דֹ
    171 דֹּ
    112 דֻ
     12 דֻּ
    496 דּ
  50911 ה
   1243 הְ
    197 הֱ
   2254 הֲ
    141 הֳ
   5879 הִ
   3216 הֵ
   4692 הֶ
  19262 הַ
     68 הַּ
  11880 הָ
    381 הֹ
     75 הֻ
   2133 הּ
   5814 ו
  24609 וְ
     71 וְּ
   2321 וִ
    133 וִּ
    221 וֵ
     79 וֵּ
    447 וֶ
     94 וֶּ
  16253 וַ
     37 וַּ
   8171 וָ
    395 וָּ
  34309 וֹ
    400 וֺ
     16 וֺּ
  37129 וּ
    934 ז
   2290 זְ
    129 זְּ
    660 זִ
    199 זִּ
    225 זֵ
     79 זֵּ
    862 זֶ
    856 זֶּ
    540 זַ
     84 זַּ
   1131 זָ
    315 זָּ
    440 זֹ
    321 זֹּ
     15 זֻ
     52 זּ
   4509 ח
   1782 חְ
    309 חֱ
   4235 חֲ
    147 חֳ
   1880 חִ
   1481 חֵ
   1492 חֶ
   5622 חַ
   4518 חָ
   1378 חֹ
    390 חֻ
   2037 ט
    546 טְ
     83 טְּ
    438 טִ
     89 טִּ
    275 טֵ
    233 טֵּ
    238 טֶ
     64 טֶּ
    495 טַ
    118 טַּ
    757 טָ
    387 טָּ
    199 טֹ
    105 טֹּ
     58 טֻ
     12 טֻּ
    215 טּ
  86613 י
  12520 יְ
     90 יְּ
  11432 יִ
   4174 יִּ
   1055 יֵ
   1087 יֵּ
   1151 יֶ
    219 יֶּ
   2734 יַ
   2574 יַּ
   6675 יָ
   3235 יָּ
    918 יֹ
   2687 יֹּ
     79 יֻ
     29 יֻּ
   1511 יּ
   1401 כ
     87 ך
   2501 כְ
   7414 ךְ
   2387 כְּ
     24 ךְּ
     19 כֲ
   1446 כִ
   5324 כִּ
   1169 כֵ
    755 כֵּ
   3313 כֶ
    546 כֶּ
   1593 כַ
   1777 כַּ
   3432 כָ
   6442 ךָ
   4263 כָּ
    102 ךָּ
    892 כֹ
   1919 כֹּ
    112 כֻ
    205 כֻּ
    543 כּ
  29208 ל
  14080 לְ
    534 לְּ
     27 לֲ
   6414 לִ
    347 לִַ
    285 לִָ
    362 לִּ
   4152 לֵ
    657 לֵּ
   5273 לֶ
    878 לֶּ
   5377 לַ
    433 לַּ
   9747 לָ
    979 לָּ
   9026 לֹ
    100 לֹּ
    181 לֻ
     62 לֻּ
    504 לּ
   3783 מ
  41446 ם
   7046 מְ
    743 מְּ
  12658 מִ
   2070 מִּ
   4467 מֵ
    260 מֵּ
   4449 מֶ
   1740 מֶּ
   7586 מַ
   1094 מַּ
   5306 מָ
   2031 מָּ
   3294 מֹ
    103 מֹּ
    178 מֻ
     50 מֻּ
   1017 מּ
   4977 נ
  15258 ן
   3665 נְ
    401 נְּ
   7147 נִ
    618 נִּ
   5744 נֵ
   1001 נֵּ
   2048 נֶ
    290 נֶּ
   2948 נַ
    325 נַּ
   7422 נָ
     40 ןָ
   1257 נָּ
   1160 נֹ
    147 נֹּ
    115 נֻ
    824 נּ
   3281 ס
   1506 סְ
     92 סְּ
    832 סִ
    103 סִּ
    559 סֵ
    236 סֵּ
    762 סֶ
     85 סֶּ
    506 סַ
    109 סַּ
    818 סָ
    202 סָּ
    245 סֹ
     83 סֹּ
     93 סֻ
     23 סֻּ
    133 סּ
   5863 ע
   1263 עְ
    285 עֱ
   6922 עֲ
     60 עֳ
   3630 עִ
   3157 עֵ
   1476 עֶ
  12633 עַ
   7847 עָ
   1640 עֹ
    256 עֻ
   1926 פ
   2560 ף
   3329 פְ
   1750 פְּ
    931 פִ
    784 פִּ
    454 פֵ
    244 פֵּ
    938 פֶ
    548 פֶּ
    724 פַ
   1033 פַּ
   1678 פָ
   1622 פָּ
    205 פֹ
    426 פֹּ
     48 פֻ
     32 פֻּ
    302 פּ
   1033 צ
   3290 ץ
   3006 צְ
    145 צְּ
   1678 צִ
    289 צִּ
   1200 צֵ
    184 צֵּ
    434 צֶ
     34 צֶּ
    936 צַ
    245 צַּ
   1489 צָ
    305 צָּ
    446 צֹ
    162 צֹּ
     94 צֻ
     81 צּ
   3562 ק
   3172 קְ
    193 קְּ
     71 קֳ
     39 קֳּ
   1444 קִ
    197 קִּ
    564 קֵ
    246 קֵּ
    803 קֶ
    157 קֶּ
   1229 קַ
    463 קַּ
   2146 קָ
    542 קָּ
    882 קֹ
    233 קֹּ
    196 קֻ
     24 קֻּ
    164 קּ
  28761 ר
   9030 רְ
     93 רֲ
   5263 רִ
   3509 רֵ
   5223 רֶ
   3519 רַ
  10247 רָ
   2427 רֹ
    268 רֻ
    301 ש
   4318 שְׂ
  10557 שְׁ
    118 שְּׂ
    548 שְּׁ
     12 שֲׁ
   1180 שִׂ
   4058 שִׁ
     66 שִּׂ
    400 שִּׁ
    570 שֵׂ
   2013 שֵׁ
     39 שֵּׂ
    230 שֵּׁ
    936 שֶׂ
   8305 שֶׁ
     20 שֶּׂ
    375 שֶּׁ
    457 שַׂ
   1840 שַׁ
     28 שַּׂ
    212 שַּׁ
   2138 שָׂ
   6365 שָׁ
    648 שָּׂ
   1597 שָּׁ
    147 שֹׂ
    919 שֹׁ
    133 שֹּׁ
     15 שֻׂ
    530 שֻׁ
     46 שֻּׁ
   1388 שׂ
   7656 שׁ
    265 שּׁ
  30293 ת
   2736 תְ
   2119 תְּ
   2989 תִ
   4860 תִּ
   1509 תֵ
   1492 תֵּ
   1281 תֶ
   1230 תֶּ
   1968 תַ
   1996 תַּ
   4722 תָ
   4009 תָּ
    366 תֹ
    605 תֹּ
     97 תֻ
     50 תֻּ
   1242 תּ

Not all of them are used in vocalized modern Hebrew texts, but this does cover all of the letter+diacritic combinations you would ever encounter in modern texts. In modern Hebrew, there are also girshayim ״ and geresh ׳ used on special occasions (abbreviations, letter names, designation of originally foreign sounds) - they are frequently replaced with quotation marks: " and ', respectively. (A similar function is fulfilled in some exotic cases by maqaf ־  which is as well often replaced with a simple hyphen -.)
Yiddish uses the basic set of 22 letters and final variants. The main letter+nikkud combinations in modern texts are: אַ אָ פּ. Additional ligatures appearing in some orthographies are: ײ װ ױ. Disregarding some rare spelling systems, the only combination with a diacritic for these ligatures is ײַ. Some Yiddish orthographies use the diacritic rafe which is generally not used in the vocalization of Tanakh above or in modern Hebrew: all together it can be found in the following combinations: תֿ, פֿ, כֿ, בֿ. Combinations וּ and יִ are used in the Soviet and YIVO systems and שׂ is used in the latter as well. In some older spellings which point every word of Semitic origin (and sometimes every other word as well, although only a handful of diacritics are used for those), you can theoretically encounter essentially any vocalization listed above for Tanakh.
Also notice that the above does not exhaust the graphics used across all Jewish languages. E.g. some orthographies of Judezmo have more diacritics such as in דﬞ and Judeo-Arabic uses the ligature ﭏ‎.
Not sure if this is relevant for what you are trying to achieve, but some letter+diacritic combinations have their own pre-combined unicode symbols.

To start with, there are 22 basic letters representing consonants. Some of them have special word-final forms, but these should only appear at the end of a word, so if this is actually a word and not a random assortment of letters you don't have to count those.
Six of those can be altered with the dagesh, a mark indicating it's pronounced as a stop rather than a fricative. Most of these don't actually alternate between stops and fricatives any more, but the dagesh remains.
One of them is known as both sin and shin, and can be written with dots on the left or right to disambiguate if necessary. So that's two more (undotted, sin-dot, and shin-dot), bringing us to 30.
Each of these can be written with eleven different neqqudoth (if you include the variations of shwa), or none at all. So multiply that by twelve, and you get 360 different "letters" by your definition.
(I haven't included the geresh, which is used to indicate certain foreign sounds. If you want that, you have to decide what to count it as. It could potentially add five more consonants.)

The six begedkefet letters are the only ones that can be written with a dagesh qal, but any letter other than aleph, he, het, ayin, and (typically) resh can receive a dagesh hazaq marking original gemination. Begedkefet letters are pronounced the same regardless of which type of dagesh they have received, but it is important for correctly interpretting the neighbouring vowel signes. Aleph and he can also receive a mapiq (marking that they should be pronounced) which looks identical to the dagesh. That leaves just het, ayin, and (usually) resh that can't receive a dot in the middle of them

@Tristan Is that still used in Modern Hebrew though? I thought that was only used for older stages of the language.

pointing in general is infrequent in Modern Hebrew (except in certain contexts ofc), but I believe it's still in use. It isn't possible to properly distinguish qamatz qatan from qamatz gadol without it, and that distinction's still present. Dagesh in resh is solely found in Biblical Hebrew though, and even then it's rare
